# SwiftUI: Pattern matching causes view to animate incorrectly

Tags: swiftui

I'm implementing a very simple view (`ChildView`) that will slide up from the bottom of `ParentView` when a button is tapped. I've reproduced the issue below in a minimal example.

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var foo: String?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if case .some = foo {
                Text("Foo")
            }

            Spacer()

            Text("Bar")
        }
        .offset(y: foo != nil ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var foo: String?

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    foo = "Foo"
                }
            }) {
                Text("Tap me")
            }

            ChildView(foo: $foo)
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 500)
    }
}
```

I pass a binding into `ChildView` that is a simple `String?` here, but ultimately it will be an enum instance which I will switch on inside `ChildView`.

The problem is that `Text("Foo")` inside `ChildView` doesn't slide up from the bottom, but rather fades in place. `Text("Bar")` slides correctly, and the only difference is that the former touches the `foo` binding. See GIF below:

[image]

One can observe the same thing if `foo` was an enum and we switched on it.

**What is going on?**

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004963/swiftui-animation-not-occurring-on-update-of-binding) question, but the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the binding changes, the ChildView changes two things: Show "foo" which hadn't been there before, and change the offset of anything else to 0.
So animation will only work on what has been there before. i.e. "Bar".

But you can change the value of elements, that are already there:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var foo: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(foo ?? "")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Bar")
        }
        .offset(y: foo != nil ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it. As I wrote in the question: "I pass a binding into `ChildView` that is a simple `String?` here, but ultimately it will be an enum instance which I will switch on inside `ChildView`." I added that part just to show that touching `foo` breaks the animation.

Comment: if you want animation from one state to another (in this case offset), the element you want to animate must already be there. But you could change it's value from "" to "Foo" ... -- I updated the answer code :)

Comment: Right, of course, there's this whole identity thing that I overlooked a bit. In my case it will be more complex because I need to have complex subviews inside `ChildView`, but at least you pointed out that I were thinking a bit wrong about this, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

As a bonus, now with enum, hope it helps.
The enum switch case sets a state var which controls the view.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @Binding var myEnum: MyEnum?
    @State private var label = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(label)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Bar")
        }
        .offset(y: myEnum != nil ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        
        .onChange(of: myEnum, perform: { newValue in
            switch myEnum {
            case .fun: label = "Fun"
            case .work: label = "Work"
            case .home: label = "Home"
            default: label = ""
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, the `onChange(of:perform)` can definitely be helpful, thanks! :-)